# Spring boot controller not mapping to url

Tags: spring-boot

[image]

[image]

First time using Spring Boot. I was expecting localhost:8080/hello to render grades.html, but I don't think the controller is working.

Comment: Remove abstract identifier from the controller class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller class needs to be a concrete class not abstract. Remove the abstract keyword.

```
package com.ltp.gradesubmission.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class GradeController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String getGrades() {
        return "grades";
    }

    @GetMapping("/dog")
    public String getDog() {
        return "dog";
    }
}
```

- Consider the use of RequestMapping annotation.

Please do not paste images, it's way more convenient to post code snippet.
Hope this helps.